# Valarray and custom allocator

Tags: c++, stl, containers, valarray

Why `std::valarray` does not support custom allocators? How designed its memory management? Is there `new`-based or `malloc`-based allocator used?
All other containers generally provide a possibility to specify custom allocator. Say, `std::vector` in `libstdc++` have corresponding template parameter `Allocator` and I can specify `__gnu_cxx::__mt_alloc` as allocator.

Answer (score -1):

> Why std::valarray does not support custom allocators?

Because `std::valarray` is not a dynamic array (Like `std::vector`). Its a kind of optimized version of vector for numeric computation, designed to rely on SIMDs and similar optimizations.

From [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray):

> std::valarray and helper classes are defined to be free of certain
>   forms of aliasing, thus allowing operations on these classes to be
>   optimized similar to the effect of the keyword restrict in the C
>   programming language. In addition, functions and operators that take
>   valarray arguments are allowed to return proxy objects to make it
>   possible for the compiler to optimize an expression [...] avoiding any temporaries or multiple passes.

As you can see, its not a simple dynamic array. Its a dynamic array designed to hold numeric values and do vectorized computations over them, via many optimizations.